# Error File 'dcolumn.sty' not found [ABNTEX2 ]

Tags: abntex2

I'm trying use the ABNTEX2 but I always receive this message in both editors Textmaker and Texstudio.

My example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%--- Outros pacotes ---%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-3in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-3in} \setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{20cm} \setlength{\topmargin}{-3cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2.5cm} \setlength{\headsep}{0.4in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.5in} \setlength{\parindent}{1.0cm}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%--- Pacotes ---%



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%--- teoremas, ... ---%
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lema}[teo]{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}[teo]{Proposição}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corolário}
\newtheorem{defini}{Definição}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exe}{Exemplo}[chapter]
\newtheorem{nota}{\sc Nota}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observação}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

%--- Nomes especiais (em português)

\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.e.}}
\newcommand{\cte}{\mathrm{cte.}}
\newcommand{\dist}{\mathrm{dist}}
\newcommand{\ang}{\mbox{ang}}
\newcommand{\mmin}{\mbox{\scriptsize mín}}
\renewcommand{\inf}{\mbox{inf}}
\renewcommand{\max}{\mbox{max}}
\renewcommand{\min}{\mbox{min}}
\newcommand{\ibox}[1]{\mbox{\rule[-2mm]{0mm}{6mm}{$#1$}}}
\renewcommand{\d}{\hspace{.1cm}\textrm{d}}

%--- Símbolos de conjuntos
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathbb{X}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%---Ambientes
%\newenvironment{defini2}{\noindent\textrm{DEFINIÇÃO}}
\newenvironment{demo}{\noindent\textit{Demonstração:}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\preambulo{Modelo canônico de Relatório Técnico e/ou Científico em conformidade
com as normas ABNT apresentado à comunidade de usuários \LaTeX.}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

%\begin{minipage}{15.5cm}

\begin{center}

nothing

\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: dcolumn is part of the core "required" tools collection, so if you do not have it then you have a broken latex installation,

Comment: however I do get the errors `! LaTeX Error: Command \nota already defined.`  and `! Class memoir Error: Font command \sc is not supported`  (`\sc` has not been defined by default in latex for almost 30 years, use `\scshape`)

Comment: the editor you use will never affect the tex behaviour, you have not said which tex you are using, probably miktex or texlive but in either case you should update the tex system to add the `latex-tools` bundle although as I said any site that has latex at all should already have dcolumn.

Comment: The solution was remove and add the miktex, because I already updated recently.  Thank you everyone.